# How does Avatar attain cosmic state at climax fight?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

At the climax, Avatar Aang picks up a fight with the Fire lord (*could be, Phoenix king*) Ozai. In the midst of that, he accidentally hits his back (*a wound from last confrontation from Azula at the Earth realm*), he will get the past memories of all avatars in a row and he connects with cosmic avatar state suddenly.

How did all of those happen? Did Aang somehow lost his attachments with Earthly elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aang had already succeeded in severing his earthly attachment in the season 2 finale. You can see that he encased himself in a crystal enclosure and unlocked his 7th chakra, starting to levitate when he got hit by Azula's lightning mid-transformation sequence.

This led to his back chakra gate being unable to open. Aang recognizes this, as he casually comments on it during "The Ember Island Players":

> Katara: Are you all right?
>
> Aang [angered]: No, I'm not! I hate this play! [Yanks his hat off and throws it on the ground.]
>
> Katara: I know it's upsetting, but it sounds like you're overreacting.
>
> Aang: Overreacting? ***If I hadn't blocked my chakra, I'd probably be in the Avatar State right now***!

While fighting Ozai, Aang hits his back, unblocking his chakra path, and thus is able to access the Avatar State.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We know that if the Avatar dies while in the Avatar state, the Avatar cycle will be broken (Avatar Roku, S2E01, "The Avatar State").

This is what happened when Azula killed Aang (S2E20). He was literally dead until Katara was able to use the Spirit Water from the Oasis at the North Pole (obtained during S2E01 from Master Pakku). The Spirit Water interacted with the Avatar Spirit to bring him back to life, but there was a problem. The location that Azula's lightning struck was no coincidence, as it hit his third chakra, the solar plexus chakra, which regulates the body's ability to absorb external energies; the lightning was drawn right in to where it would do the most damage. The lightning fused that chakra closed, and not even the Spirit Water was strong enough to restore the connection to the Avatar State.

When his back was struck during the fight with Ozai, it broke loose that fused chakra, and the energy was able to flow. Do you remember what the guru said (S2E19)? Once a chakra has been blocked, and then cleared, all the rest can flow like a river. When his chakra becomes unblocked, the power he already had access to previously was restored.